# Splitting an empty string in Java seems to violate documentation by not discarding trailing empty strings

Tags: java, regex, string

```
System.out.println(",".split(",", 0).length);
System.out.println("".split(",", 0).length);
```

prints:

> 0
>   1

This seems odd. According to the documentation for [String.split(pattern, n)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String,%20int)),

> If n is zero then the pattern will be applied as many times as possible, the array can have any length, and **trailing empty strings will be discarded**.

In the second case, when splitting an empty string, this rule seems to be ignored. Is this expected behavior?

Comment: Removing trailing empty strings only makes sense *if these empty strings ware created as result of splitting*, but here `"".split(",")` we didn't split anything, so as result we are getting array containing original string `[""]`, so its length is `1`.

Comment: Another interesting case is `"".split("")`. Here result array is also `[""]` which means its length is `1`. It is worth to remembering that `"".split(anything)` will always return `[""]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As from docs

> If the expression does not match any part of the input then the
>   `resulting array has just one element, namely this string`

`"".split(",", 0).length` mean it is similar to this

```
    System.out.println(new String[]{""}.length);
```

There was no `,` in the string `""` so the array contain single element `""` an empty string , result in array length as `1`

another example

```
    System.out.println("aaa".split(",", 0).length); // 1
    System.out.println("aaa".split("," , 0)[0]);    // aaa
```

Comment: I agree: in the 2nd example there is only a blank input string: since you don't have a separator in the input, there is no **trailing** blank string.